# iOS - GKPeerPickerController [picker dismiss] crash

Tags: ios, crash, bluetooth, gamekit

I'm using GKPeerPickerController, this is my simple code:

```
- (IBAction)turnOn:(id)sender {
    GKPeerPickerController *peerpicker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc]init];
    peerpicker.delegate = self;
    peerpicker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
    [peerpicker show];
}

-(GKSession*)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type
{
    [picker dismiss];
    NSLog(@"picker Dismissed");
    return nil;
}
```

turnOn is an IBAction fired from a button. The problem is that after the picker is dismissed the app crash with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, why? How can I solve?
This is from the console:

```
2013-06-01 14:28:57.659 iShare[829:907] BTM: attaching to BTServer
2013-06-01 14:29:00.873 iShare[829:907] BTM: local device power state changed
2013-06-01 14:29:00.876 iShare[829:907] BTM: power is now on
2013-06-01 14:29:00.883 iShare[829:907] picker Dismissed
```

My iPhone 3GS is jailbreaked, can it be a problem?
Thanks!!

Comment: [picker dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; try thsi one

Comment: this method doesn't exist, so it can't compile (I tried)

Comment: Sory for this i will not read your question carefullythat's why..

Comment: [picker removeFromSuperview]; try this one..

Comment: there isn't neither this one, I'm not sure if the problem is dismissing the picker, from the log you can read that the program is able to write a log after dismiss

Answer (score 1):

You are dismissing your picker from sessionForConnection which is an unusual choice, however calling [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; instead of [picker dismiss] should work better for you.

Comment: If you are using iOS 6+ you should be using - (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion, please see the documentation on deprecated methods as they will almost always refer to the replacement.